# Timeperiod increase /Append for logs in GCP

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform

I have a bucket which have 2 folders one of them is log .Bucket is set to a rule of 30 day period after any files it deletes . Now other folder is retaining the files for 30 days but my logs are neither getting appended nor any folder is created which can hold my previous logs.

Any possibility i can raise my log period , or append to the original one , Could it possible to add folders on day wise?

Sqooper is used to import data to GCP

Below code is making the log

today=$(date +"%F")
OUTPUT =$run_path/pathname_$(mode)_$(today).log

gsutil -m copy is used to upload into GCP

Comment: To understand your scenario, do you have object holds on the items that are not deleted? I have found information here[1] which explains:
“An object lifecycle Delete action will not take effect on an object while the object either has an object hold placed on it or a retention policy that it has not yet fulfilled. Any Delete action that would occur while an object had a hold or retention policy restriction instead occurs after the restrictions no longer apply to the object.”
[1]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

Comment: Hey Christian, Yes .both folders are in the same bucket and rule for both is same but my folder is acting what is required but the log folder does not seems to be.